# How to skip DXA default website items on Production Environment during DXA installation

Tags: web8, dxa, topology-manager, dxa-1.6

I am installing DXA 1.6 framework with SDL web8 on production environment and i do not want default DXA website specific any items to be present on prod servers. Like default DXA website, DXA specific Business Process Types in CMS. On Prod I can deploy only my custom website,In CMS I need DXA Master, DXA site Type publications only (will delete other DXA publicaitons) so that i can inherit them in my custom publications.

In other words how can I skip step1 and step3 which are mentioned in the default DXA installation. Can I directly execute step2 script and for step 1 and step 3 do it manually using Topology commands specific to my custom web application

1)Creating the DXA Topology (ttm-prepare.ps1) - SKIP

2)Installing the content (cms-import.ps1) - Need this to inherit DXA Master, DXA site Type

3)Installing the web-application (web-install.ps1)- SKIP

**Alternate Option:**

1)Creating the DXA Topology (ttm-prepare.ps1) - Execute this as step 1; but if you see it ask for DXA staging and live website url to configure. How I can skip this I just want my custom website to configure for staging and live. Is it fine if I enter my custom website URL here ? or what should be the best approach here ?

2)Installing the content (cms-import.ps1) - (step2)Instead of executing cms-import.ps1 use Content Porter to Import publications with content from Dev CMS to PROD CMS. This will include my custom publications as well as DXA Master and DXA Site Type publication.

3)Installing the web-application (web-install.ps1)- SKIP this since i do not need to deploy DXA default website on PROD. To deploy my custom website do manuall steps to deploy website on App server. Is this Fine ?

Comment: Ad 1) If you have already defined Websites/apps in Topology Manager for your DXA Web App, you can terminate the `ttm-imports.ps1` script when it asks for your DXA Website base URL (at that point it has already created the Topology Types). If you didn't define them yet, just enter the URLs you will be using for your DXA Websites; the script will take care of registering them in Topology Manager (and link them to the DXA Site Type).

Comment: Ad 3) Of course, it is not required to install the DXA example web app. If you have created your own Web App, by all means deploy it in the way which is convenient for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit surprised that you want to do a new DXA Installation on Production; I would expect items to be ported (using Content Porter) from a Test/Acceptance environment instead.

Regardless, you can use `cms-import.ps1 -importType master-only` to import only the Core DXA Items into an existing Publication in your BluePrint.

If you want the DXA Site Type Publication too, you have to also use `-importType example-publications` or just use the default `all-publications`.

It is currently not possible to import without the predefined DXA BPTs, so you will have to ensure that the associated Topology Types exist in Topology Manager (by running `ttm-prepare.ps1`), otherwise the CMS import will fail.

Again, consider porting items from Test/Acceptance using Content Porter instead (the typical thing to do in DTAP environments).

Comment: Hey Rick; As per your comments I have updated the steps Under "Alternate Option" heading in Q description; Can you please suggest if that makes sense now or needs any modification; thanks

Comment: Added my responses as comments to the new Questions (it gets a bit messy if you repurpose a Question).